# Break textarea text before it hits another element

Tags: html, css

I got a textarea and I want the text to break before it overlaps the emoji icon that is a button in my html file. I dont want it to overlap it. I would rather not give the emoji a `z-index` because it would mess other things up.

Here is code

HTML

```
<button class="emoji"></button>
<textarea rows="6" cols="60" class="divTxtArea" placeholder="Type a message.."></textarea>
```

CSS

```
.divTxtArea
{

    resize: none;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 1em;
    color:#8b959a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #e1e4e6;
    width:580px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    height:180px;
    max-height:180px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    outline: none; 
    resize:none!important;
}

div .emoji
{
    position:absolute;
    left:80%;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And here is a picture for those who did not understand

[image]

Comment: I should increase the `padding-right`. The width of the emoji plus some extra padding.

Comment: Or check my other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```css
.divTxtArea
{

    resize: none;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 1em;
    color:#8b959a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #e1e4e6;
    width:580px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    height:180px;
    max-height:180px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    outline: none; 
    resize:none!important;
}

.divTxtArea .emoji
{
    float: right;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divTxtArea textarea {

  border: none;
  width : 95%;
  height: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="divTxtArea">
  <button class="emoji"></button>
<textarea rows="6" cols="60" placeholder="Type a message.."></textarea>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah , so you just added a div and created a border around the div instead

Comment: Yes, I have added div and apply all your textarea css to that div and also set `border:none;` to text area.

Comment: Thanks this was a great solution, it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this? The pseudo-element `before` should be your emoji icon.

```css
#textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

#textarea:before {
  content:'';
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  float:right;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tincidunt et sem eget imperdiet. Vivamus id sollicitudin urna. Proin nec libero ut justo egestas fringilla ut eu diam. Ut congue, felis in pulvinar lacinia, metus diam mollis dolor, et semper tortor purus vitae felis. Aenean lorem elit, ultricies dignissim dolor.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
textarea {
resize: none;
}
```

in your CSS.

Comment: ..right.. you have it twice added to the class .divTxtArea . Tested your code, and considering the given data, it works as intended. Probably you have something else in your CSS that overrides the styling you are doing. Try using a debugging tool like "Firebug" .. see what the browser parse.